# Insert Multiple Bitmap Image into Multiple Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

In my folder, there is AA.bmp, AA.txt, BB.bmp and BB.txt

I am able to extract the data for AA.txt and BB.txt in a separate worksheet.

Am I also able to insert AA.bmp in the same sheet as AA.txt, and BB.bmp in the same sheet as BB.txt?

```
Sub ExtractData()
iPath = "C:\Users\NHWD78\Desktop\Report\Radiated Immunity\"
ifile = Dir(iPath & "*.txt")

Do While Len(ifile)
Sheets.Add , Sheets(Sheets.Count), , iPath & ifile
ifile = Dir
Range("A10:B10, A16:B19").Copy Destination:=Sheets(Sheets.Count).Range("A1")

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("A6:K600").Clear
Columns.AutoFit

Loop
End Sub
```

I have search throughout the website but only found a way to insert a fixed image with image name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will answer your query, its more of a solution than an answer which is not what this site is for, but take the time to read through it as it should be educationally useful too.

You are trying to parse a folder that has content similar to below:-

[image: Folder with text and image files in]

The result os for these to be in an Excel workbook, with a worksheet containing the text and image for each group (AA, BB, and CC)

First step I would take is to use Microsoft Scripting Runtime, this makes parsing the folder a lot easier. To enable this, within the VBA environment (known as the IDE), select 'Tools' > 'References...', scroll down to 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime' and tick it, then click 'OK' to close the dialog box.

[image: Add References in VBA]

That allows us to the File System Object, which is a very useful file and folder manipulation and interrogation feature set.

Firstly we care most about the *.txt files so lets begin by looping through them:-

```
Dim FSO     As New FileSystemObject
Dim Fldr    As Folder
Dim Fl      As File

'First we set Fldr to be the folder we care about
Set Fldr = FSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\garye\Desktop\Work")

    'Then start a loop to look through each file in the folder
    For Each Fl In Fldr.Files

        'If the files ends in .txt then we care about it (UCASE used to make it case insensitive)
        If Right(UCase(Fl.Name), 4) = ".TXT" Then

            'We have found a file

        End If

        'Do events returns the processor to the system for any other items to be process
        'very useful in a loop on a Windows based machine to stop resource hogging and lock ups
        DoEvents
    Next
Set Fldr = Nothing
```

Next on the discovery of a text file we want to create a worksheet and import the text. For the sake of this example, it will all be done in a new workbook as well.

```
Dim WkBk        As Workbook
Dim WkBk_Tmp    As Workbook
Dim WkSht       As Worksheet
Dim WkSht_Tmp   As Worksheet
Dim StrName     As String

'Create a new workbook
Set WkBk = Application.Workbooks.Add

'...

'Collect the name (i.e. AA from AA.txt)
StrName = Left(Fl.Name, Len(Fl.Name) - 4)

'Create a new worksheet in out new workbook
Set WkSht = WkBk.Worksheets.Add

    'Change the worksheet name to the file name
    WkSht.Name = StrName

    'Open the file in Excel
    Set WkBk_Tmp = Application.Workbooks.Open(Fl.Path)
        Set WkSht_Tmp = WkBk_Tmp.Worksheets(1)

            'Copy its contents into out worksheet
            WkSht_Tmp.Cells.Copy WkSht.Cells
        Set WkSht_Tmp = Nothing

        'Close the file
        WkBk_Tmp.Close 0
    Set WkBk_Tmp = Nothing
```

Next we want to insert the image if it is there:-

```
Dim Rng         As Range

'...

'See it a bmp file exists (i.e. AA.bmp)
If FSO.FileExists(Fldr.Path & "\" & StrName & ".bmp") Then

    'This get the bottom row of data as a position to insert the image
    Set Rng = WkSht.Range(WkSht.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Address).Next(2, 0)

        'Add the picture
        WkSht.Shapes.AddPicture Fldr.Path & "\" & StrName & ".bmp", msoFalse, msoCTrue, Rng.Left, Rng.Top, -1, -1

    Set Rng = Nothing

 End If
```

If we put all the above together it looks as below, hopefully this has been education in what is happening in the code, some good practices, how to approaching a task.

Option Explicit

```
Sub ExtractData()
Dim FSO         As New FileSystemObject
Dim Fldr        As Folder
Dim Fl          As File
Dim WkBk        As Workbook
Dim WkBk_Tmp    As Workbook
Dim WkSht       As Worksheet
Dim WkSht_Tmp   As Worksheet
Dim StrName     As String
Dim Rng         As Range

'Create a new workbook
Set WkBk = Application.Workbooks.Add

    'First we set Fldr to be the folder we care about
    Set Fldr = FSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\garye\Desktop\Work")

        'Then start a loop to look through each file in the folder
        For Each Fl In Fldr.Files

            'If the files ends in .txt then we care about it (UCASE used to make it case insensitive)
            If Right(UCase(Fl.Name), 4) = ".TXT" Then

                'Collect the name (i.e. AA from AA.txt)
                StrName = Left(Fl.Name, Len(Fl.Name) - 4)

                'Create a new worksheet in out new workbook
                Set WkSht = WkBk.Worksheets.Add

                    'Change the worksheet name to the file name
                    WkSht.Name = StrName

                    'Open the file in Excel
                    Set WkBk_Tmp = Application.Workbooks.Open(Fl.Path)
                        Set WkSht_Tmp = WkBk_Tmp.Worksheets(1)

                            'Copy its contents into out worksheet
                            WkSht_Tmp.Cells.Copy WkSht.Cells
                        Set WkSht_Tmp = Nothing

                        'Close the file
                        WkBk_Tmp.Close 0
                    Set WkBk_Tmp = Nothing

                    'See it a bmp file exists (i.e. AA.bmp)
                    If FSO.FileExists(Fldr.Path & "\" & StrName & ".bmp") Then

                        'This get the bottom row of data as a position to insert the image
                        Set Rng = WkSht.Range(WkSht.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Address).Next(2, 0)

                            'Add the picture
                            WkSht.Shapes.AddPicture Fldr.Path & "\" & StrName & ".bmp", msoFalse, msoCTrue, Rng.Left, Rng.Top, -1, -1

                        Set Rng = Nothing

                    End If

                Set WkSht = Nothing

            End If

            'Do events returns the processor to the system for any other items to be process
            'very useful in a loop on a Windows based machine to stop resource hogging and lock ups
            DoEvents
        Next
    Set Fldr = Nothing

Set WkBk = Nothing

MsgBox "Done!"

End Sub
```

Comment: Oh My Gosh! I really appreciate on this detail and patient explanation! This really helps me a lot and makes me more understand about VBA code! Thanks for your effort, awesome code! Regards

Answer (score 0):

`Worksheet.Shapes.AddPicture` will do it. Example below: -

```
Public Sub Sample()
Dim WkBk    As Workbook
Dim WkSht   As Worksheet
Dim Ole     As Object

Set WkBk = ThisWorkbook
    Set WkSht = WkBk.Worksheets(1)
        WkSht.Shapes.AddPicture "C:\Users\garye\Desktop\AA.bmp", msoFalse, msoCTrue, 0, 0, -1, -1
    Set WkSht = Nothing
Set WkBk = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply
but the AA.bmp and BB.bmp is just an example...the image will be always changing...
the code attached is looping to extract the txt file data, is it possible to do in same way to import the bmp file?

Comment: Yes, place `AppPictures` in a loop, the above was just an example to answer the question "Can i also insert the AA.bmp". You'll want to write it as need to fit your code.

Comment: Hi, I inserted the code provided but it will insert the image at current worksheet but not the worksheet that contain data of the txt files... and this is under the condition that i insert a full path name of the image...
i am not really understand how to make it loop and insert the image in the correct worksheet automatically...